# tokens and file streams

Tags: c++, stream, filestream, token

I study source codes of programs, (written in c++) that operate on file streams. But every now and then i stumble upon something called `tokens`. Can you please explain to me, what tokens do and why are they useful? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Stream* refers to a sequence of data elements made available over time. Data elements in streams could be of any kind: characters, strings, special-purpose data structures, etc. A text file could be trivially interpreted as a stream of characters.

In the context of programming languages, the word *token* usually refers to a sequence of one or more related characters from a stream of characters. Tokens offer a level of abstraction on top of character streams, and are often themselves grouped in streams for further processing.

The usual processing sequence in compilers of programming languages starts with *lexical analyzers* converting streams of characters into streams of tokens, which are then passed on to *parsers*. Typical representation of a token consists of a type indicator and the content of the token.

Here is an example: consider this fragment of C++ program:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    string name;
};
```

A lexer analyzer groups this program into a stream of ten tokens:

```
'class' (keyword)
'MyClass' (identifier)
'{' (opening brace)
'public' (keyword)
':' (colon)
'string' (identifier)
'name' (identifier)
';' (semicolon)
'}' (closing brace)
';' (semicolon)
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon (not on purpose, I hope).

Answer (score 1):

Tokens can be thought of as "place holders".  Tokens represent a specific entity (string), and are usually some sort of intermediary step between two equivalents.  For example, tokens are often used in parsers where they represent a given language's syntax.

Comment: so it is an abstract notion rather than some language specific feature, right?

Comment: @Abdulali indeed, it is not a language feature.  A document is made up of many tokens, and a token is the smallest meaningful unit: typically a full word, separator, or such. "123 + 456" may be represented by the tokens "123", "+", and "456".

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Back to my parser example; the first stage of a parser is a "lexer" (lexical analyser), which assigns tokens to the incoming syntax.  The tokens are arbitrary and are selected specifically for the tasks to be carried out on them later.  The more "detail" that is required, the more types of token there are defined.